# Add property to most recent object in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I'm fetching data from the database and I want to pair the id (string) and data (object) together. However, `forEach` replaces every object in the array with the current iteration's special.id. I want to only add special.id to the last object, aka special.data(), in the array.

```
//Push object into the masterEstablishments array
masterEstablishments.push(special.data());

//Add an id property to the establishment object in masterEstablishments
masterEstablishments.forEach(function(element) {
  element.id = special.id;
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using:

```
            //Push object into the masterEstablishments array
            masterEstablishments.push(special.data());
            masterEstablishments[masterEstablishments.length - 1].id = special.id;
```

or try using:

```
  let obj = {};
  obj = special.data();
  obj.id = special.id;
  masterEstablishments.push(obj);
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `condition` in your `forEach` loop.

```
masterEstablishments.forEach(function(element, i) {
  if (i === masterEstablishments.length - 1) {
    element.id = special.id;
  }
});
```

alternatively, you can access the last element

```
masterEstablishment[masterEstablishments.length - 1].id = special.id;
```